# Как правильно указывать пути в express.static?

Tags: node.js, express, path

У меня есть front end собранный vue cli и back end на node js Express. Файловая структура:
D:\programming\Web\project\frontEnd
D:\programming\Web\project\BackEnd

То есть обе папки лежат в общей папке project. В папке frontEnd есть папка dist в которой лежит production index.html моего frontEnd.
В папке BackEnd у меня находится index.js в котором инициализируется сервер. Я хочу чтобы на любой запрос выдавался один файл index.html, сервер выглядит следующим образом:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const path = require('path')
    const cors = require('cors')
    const app = express()
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../FrontEnd/dist')))
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve('../FrontEnd/dist') + '/index.html')
    })
    
    app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
      console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT} port`)
    })
```

Меня очень смущает:

`app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../FrontEnd/dist')))`

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('../FrontEnd/dist') + '/index.html')
})
```

Тк я думаю в sendFile я должен указывать только имя файла тк путь я прописал в express.static, но если в sendFile передать '/index.html' сервер запуститься и даже выдаст мой файл, но при этом в консоль выводит:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\index.html'

Подскажите оставить все как есть или есть лучшие практики для этого случая?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `app.use(express.static('dist'))`, `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вы не совсем понимаете принцип работы `express static`. Static отправляет файлы из указанной директории браузеру для использования (картинки, скрипты). [Почитайте здесь.](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html)

Вам в любом случае надо будет указывать полный путь до папки.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '<путь до папки>')).
```

(`__dirname` подставляет путь до папки со скриптом, в котором вызывается).